# Do browsers behave sensibly when download file names contain invalid characters?

Tags: http, browser

Consider an HTTP response with a `Content-Disposition` which includes a filename that would be invalid on any normal filesystem:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=a/b:c\d.txt
```

Or even more insiduously:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename*=UTF-8''%00
```

(ie, the file name is a null byte)

Will browsers deal with this in a sensible way?

For I know that Chrome 29 will replace the invalid character with a `-`, which is sensible enough… but are there browsers which will crash? Reject the download? Or otherwise cause surprising problems?

Comment: What do you mean by "sensible?"  What do you consider sensible?

Comment: Anything which wouldn't make a reasonable person's blood pressure rise? Chrome escapes them with a "-", which is sensible enough. But it wouldn't surprise me to learn that some browsers crash, reject the download, or otherwise do something which doesn't help get the download into the user's hands. Edited to clarify.

Comment: Why not just avoid these altogether?  They're clearly not valid file names.  Well-engineered web applications will simply reject them.

Comment: Because I'd like to let Windows users include a `:` in their filename, and Linux users (… possibly slightly masochistic ones?) include `\\`. Also, I'm curious.